# How to find the mass of a an object that goes on forever?

Tags: integration

Hi I am trying to the mass of the object below. I honestly have no clue how to figure it out. I thought I could just find the volume and multiply it by the density. But even that I am not sure since I'm not sure how to find the volume of something that has no bounds. I would appreciate [image]any help! Thank you!

Comment: You can compute the sum $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + \cdots$ with no bound on the number of terms, can't you? Surely you have been shown how to compute an integral over an interval with no right-side bound. (Hint: it's like the integral after "We can conclude".)

Comment: Whenever you're trying to integrate something that goes out to infinity, what you should do is take the integral up to an arbitrary value, say, integrate it between $0$ and $a$, and then take the limit as $a$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\rho = 1$ it is straight forward:

$$m = \int_0^{\infty}\rho\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\left(- \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right)dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+x^2}dx$$ $$ = 2 \lim_{x\to \infty}\arctan(x)= \pi$$

Comment: Here, you multiplied density and the area in between the two curves. Why? I thought mass = volume * density? Don't I need to find the volume of the area between the two curves and then multiply by density?

Comment: @NikoH It's a two dimensional shape, so the spatial extent is measured in area (rather than volume), and the density has units of mass per area.

Comment: oh that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. As a first step, you can compute the indefinite integral of the curve to get the amount of mass between 0 and some point $b$ on the x-axis. $\int_0^b f(x) dx$.
2. To compute the total amount of mass, you can integrate out to infinity: $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$. An integral out to infinity is defined as the limit of a finite integral: $\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^b f(x)dx$. This is limit of the integral you calculated in the previous step.